# Download functionality in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

i would like to use the functionality to allow table data to be downloaded by a simple button click as described on
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/download

I hoped i could get a working example on "view source", but its only code snippets needed to configure it.
Could someone give me a complete example how to use it?

I got so far, that i have the table running and the buttons are also present, i am just missing the buttons actually doing something on clicking them.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day
Ingo

Answer (score 0):

The complete example is right there on the page you linked.  Click the green "View Source" button located under the table, which will expand some snippets.  Under the "JavaScript" snippets there are button click handlers commented with `//trigger download of data.*** file`.  That code uses jQuery to specify what the button calls when it is clicked.  The buttons call `table.download()` with parameters to specify the format and download filename.

You can also see it here: http://tabulator.info/examples/4.2?#download